# What is the name of PIE "en+Consonant" > PGmc "in+Consonant" process?

Tags: proto-germanic

What is the name of changing PIE  "en+Consonant" to PGmc  "in+Consonant" process (*pent- >  *finþaną)?

Comment: It’s probably a law named after someone, since pretty much every development in Indo-European studies ends up being Someone’s Law – but I don’t know whose. As a general development, it’s just _prenasal raising_.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have a name. We just say and remember the rule along the lines of what you describe.